# Why does web3.js throw anonymous errors and swallow errors?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

web3.js throws a lot of errors with no stack trace, making it hard to debug.

for example:

```
./node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:    throw 'invalid address';
./node_modules/web3/dist/web3-light.js:    throw 'invalid address';
./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js:    throw 'invalid address';
```

These should be throw(Error('invalid address')), preferably adding the contents of whatever structure is causing the problem.

Also, in Http provider, any XML related issues get swallowed and thrown away, e.g.

```
HttpProvider.prototype.send = function (payload) {
    var request = this.prepareRequest(false);

    try {
        request.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    } catch(error) {
        throw errors.InvalidConnection(this.host);
    }
```

error should be continued in the throw or it's very hard to debug.

Is there a reason for errors to be thrown this way?  Can this be changed?

Comment: Probably the best place for these kind of questions/suggestions is the Github repo for web3.js. The first problem you mention was fixed in https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/402, pending release.

Comment: sorry, not every repro is paying attention to issues, and I did mention this in the past on Gitter and in a comment on another issue.  But you are looking at issues, so thanks.  I did submit an issue to mirror this.  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/411.  If you want the answer karma just post that as the answer, or I will after a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

These issues are unintentional and are being fixed.

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/411 was submitted to track these issues.

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/402 fixes the first issue.

Second issue is probably more complicated and will hopefully be discussed in the issue tracker.